# SQL Query to return Month days as Columns and Total Hours as Row

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, time-and-attendance

i am working on an Attendance report were I need to create a SQL Query from one table to return the attendance of employees net hours worked over the month. 
Day of the month should be as a column and in the rows should be the total Hours of employee.

The Table is having 6 Columns ( Employee Name, Dept , Position, Time In , Time Out and Total Hours

[Picture for Selecting * From the Attendance Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOf4J.jpg)

i want to return the values as the following:

**EmployeeName**  | **1st**  | **2nd** | **3rd** | **4th** | ...... |**30 June**

---

**Emp 1**        | 10:30 |   | 10:40 | | 10:10 | | 10:21 |

The Days column should be returned in a parameter so i can add it to crystal report.

Table Structure 
if you can advise please.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE statment like this:

```
        SELECT EmployeeName,
               (CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE) = 2017 AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE) = 6 AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE) = 1 then totalHours ELSE NULL END) AS "01/06",
               (CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE) = 2017 AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE) = 6 AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE) = 2 then totalHours ELSE NULL END) AS "02/06",
               .
               .
               .
               (CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE) = 2017 AND  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE) = 6 AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE) = 30 then totalHours ELSE NULL END) AS "30/06"

FROM Attendance
```

So, for each day a new column will be created.

Comment: i am already getting the difference in TimeIn and Time out as this table is giving all the values. please check the picture/

Comment: with the request I have posted, it will return the needed result. Like this:
EmployeeName | 01/06 | 02/06 | 03/06 | . .. . . . . .. | 30/06
vivek...               | 05:07:| . . . . . .. . . . .

Comment: each 'Case' will create a column for the wanted Day

Answer (score 0):

I used something like this

```
        CREATE TABLE `AxsLog` (
`id`    integer NOT NULL UNIQUE,
`Logon` text NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp,
`Logoff`    text NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp,
`Duration`  text NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`SysDat`    text NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp,
PRIMARY KEY(`id`) );
```

You can easily add an FK column for each row in your user table.

Keep the logon id for each entry, then update that line on logoff

```
UPDATE  AxsLog
Set Duration= (SELECT sum( strftime('%s', logoff) - strftime('%s', logon) ) 
/60 FROM AxsLog WHERE id= 1 )
WHERE id= 1 ;
```

To build a report, use something like this. This query only gives a total per month.

```
select total(Duration)  
FROM AxsLog where substr(sysdat,6,2) = 'month'
```

Answer (score 0):

your requirement can be fulfill by using crosstab report or if u want to achieve in sql then use pivot